# does python find errors where there are none?

Tags: python, plot

while plotting functions with heaviside function I came up with this piece of code, in Idle:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_i = [-5, 5]
n = np.linspace(n_i[0], n_i[1], 1E3)

u1 [n+30>=0] = 1
u2 [n-15>=0] =1
u3 = u1 - u2

x = np.sin(2*np.pi*(n/15))*u3

plt.axis([-30,15,-5,5])


plt.xlabel('$n$',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('$x(n)$',fontsize=20)
plt.stem(n, x, "--k", linefmt='black', basefmt='black')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

and prior to today, it ran without errors, same with all other of my plots, I've been dealing with python for two years now and throughout classes it had the habit of finding errors where even teachers don't see them. am I missing something here? it says "u1 is not defined", but it is. I even compared with coworkers and classmates alike, haven't seen it put in any other way in the code for the plot. help!

Comment: its not defined ... there is no `u1 = ` or `import u1` anywhere ...

Comment: No, `u1` is not defined. Neither is `u2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to assign a value to `u1[...]` without even having created `u1`.

You should init `u1` before trying to init its elements.

Comment: so you're telling me I need the "my_array = array(u1, [n+30>=0])" condition?
but then it lacks the heaviside function restriction, in which u(n) = 1 if t>=0 and u(n)= 0 if t<0, no?

Comment: @TwistedMaze: you need something that assigns the name `u1`. There is no such name defined in your Python code. I have no idea what your code is supposed to achieve. `my_array = array(u1, [n+30>=0])` would not assign anything to `u1`, it'll assign to the name `my_array`, but the expression will fail as you have no `u1` defined.

Comment: @TwistedMaze No, you should just declare your `u1`. For instance as a dictionnary (or something else, depending of what you want) : `u1 = {}`. And *only then*, adding elements to it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's supposed to represent a graphical visualization of a mathematical function through the stem function in matplotlib. the exercise has the heaviside function limiting the actual function. I looked up examples in python and applied it. up to today it had no errors and out of the blue - "name u1 is not defined"

Comment: @vmonteco: the expression used suggests that `u1` and `u2` should be numpy arrays too.

Comment: @vmonteco I see, I know what to do now, thank you very much :)

Comment: @TwistedMaze: this code could **never** have run. Something changed.

Comment: I have about  half-a-dozen of exercises done this way and they ran completely, even showing the plot window so...go figure *shrugs*
there's probably something I'm missing so I don't blame you for stating that.